# How can I convert Calendar value to String in android studio?

Tags: java, android, string, date, calendar

I have Calendar value which is from Date Picker and I want to convert this value to String format "yyyy-MM-dd"

This is my Date Picker code. I save the selected values to startYear, startMonth and startDay.

```
    ipDcEventStartDay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(DoubleCheckEventActivity.this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                    startYear = year;
                    startMonth = month;
                    startDay = dayOfMonth;

                    ipDcEventStartDay.setText(startYear+ "-" + (startMonth+1) + "-" + startDay);
                    ipDcEventStartDay.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
                }
            }, today.get(Calendar.YEAR), today.get(Calendar.MONTH), today.get(Calendar.DATE));
            dpd.show();
        }
    });
```

and then I tried to convert these values to String in this way. But the log result is 0002-12-31 not what I selected from Date Picker.

```
Calendar start = Calendar.getInstance();
start.set(startYear, startMonth, startDay); 
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date startDate = start.getTime(); // Convert to Date
String strStartDate = sdf.format(startDate); // Convert to String
Log.d("start", strStartDate); // this result is 0002-12-31
```

Comment: Basic problem diagnosis step - print out startYear, startMonth, startDay (or examine them in a debugger) just before you set them into the 'start' Calendar, to make sure the values are what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

Never use `Calendar`. That terrible class was supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes.

## `LocalDate`

Instead, use [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html) for a date-only value with no time-of-day and no offset or time zone.

```java
LocalDate x = LocalDate.now() ;
String output = x.toString() ;
```

Build from parts.

```
LocalDate x = LocalDate.of( y , m , d ) ;
```

Get parts.

```
int y = x.getYear() ;
int m = x.getMonthValue() ;
int d = x.getDayOfMonth() ;
```

Comment: I sw''r that the `month` from the date picker is foolishly 0-based like in `Calendar`, so the OP will need to feed `month + 1` into the `LocalDate`. Nice answer.

Answer (score 0):

If your code goes like this; the log shows the date value before picking any dates. So you see the value for year: 0, month: 0 and day:0 (which is shown as 0002-12-31). (Note that the code inside onDateSet() method runs asynchronously, when the user picks a date.)

```
int startYear, startMonth, startDay;
Calendar today = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();

ipDcEventStartDay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(DoubleCheckEventActivity.this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                startYear = year;
                startMonth = month;
                startDay = dayOfMonth;

                ipDcEventStartDay.setText(startYear+ "-" + (startMonth+1) + "-" + startDay);
                ipDcEventStartDay.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
            }
        }, today.get(Calendar.YEAR), today.get(Calendar.MONTH), today.get(Calendar.DATE));
        dpd.show();
    }
});
// startYear, startMonth, startDay are not initialized yet and equal 0.
Calendar start = Calendar.getInstance();
start.set(startYear, startMonth, startDay); 
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date startDate = start.getTime(); // Convert to Date
String strStartDate = sdf.format(startDate); // Convert to String
Log.d("start", strStartDate); // this result is 0002-12-31
```

Instead; if you try to convert your Date to String "after the values are set" (Shown below) .You can see it will be correctly converted.

```
int startYear, startMonth, startDay;
Calendar today = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();

ipDcEventStartDay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(DoubleCheckEventActivity.this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                startYear = year;
                startMonth = month;
                startDay = dayOfMonth;

                ipDcEventStartDay.setText(startYear+ "-" + (startMonth+1) + "-" + startDay);
                ipDcEventStartDay.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));

                //************************************************************
                //Now we have the picked values.
                Calendar start = Calendar.getInstance();
                start.set(startYear, startMonth, startDay); 
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                Date startDate = start.getTime(); // Convert to Date
                String strStartDate = sdf.format(startDate); // Convert to String
                Log.d("start", strStartDate); // this result is 0002-12-31
                //************************************************************
            }
        }, today.get(Calendar.YEAR), today.get(Calendar.MONTH), today.get(Calendar.DATE));
        dpd.show();
    }
});
```

Comment: but if I put those codes in the ipDcEventStartDay.setOnClickListener, I can't get approach to the String strStartDate Value outside of ipDcEventStartDay.setOnClickListener.. I need string value to save in Firebase and also 
 give this value to another activity like this one `intent.putExtra("eventPlaceName", choicePlaceName);`

Comment: Actually you can fetch your values in both ways but in the end you need to fire your save method "after" any date picked. If you try to save them without waiting the user pick a date, the values will not be initialized. By nature you need to wait until the user picks a date and only after that you will be able to save that "picked Date" in any form. (Probably inside your "onDateSet(...)" method by passing the string value, such as saveToFirebase(dateValueAsString))

Answer (score -1):

**Let's see the simple code to convert Date to String**

*Basic*

```
 Date date = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();  
            DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss");  
            String strDate = dateFormat.format(date);  
            System.out.println("Converted String: " + strDate);
```

*Advanced*

```
  Date date = new Date();  
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");  
String strDate = formatter.format(date);  
System.out.println("Date Format with MM/dd/yyyy : "+strDate);  

formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-M-yyyy hh:mm:ss");  
strDate = formatter.format(date);  
System.out.println("Date Format with dd-M-yyyy hh:mm:ss : "+strDate);  

formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy");  
strDate = formatter.format(date);  
System.out.println("Date Format with dd MMMM yyyy : "+strDate);  

formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy zzzz");  
strDate = formatter.format(date);  
System.out.println("Date Format with dd MMMM yyyy zzzz : "+strDate);  

formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("E, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z");  
strDate = formatter.format(date);  
System.out.println("Date Format with E, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z : "+strDate);
```

}

Comment: How is it different from the OP is already doing in the question? Is there any reason to believe that it will give a different result?

Comment: Yes. 'Date Format with MM/dd/yyyy' Check this

Comment: More important than not getting 0002-12-31, more important than getting the correct date? I beg to differ.